# How to show the completion popup in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I have installed `Bootstrap 3 Snippets` plugin in Sublime Text 3 to use it when working with Bootstrap as this guy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWp6J7Q59KE
but I do not know how to open the completion popup.

How can I show the completion popup in Sublime Text 3, as in the Screen shot, to select `Snippat-bs3-html5-template`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Sublime Text doesn't show the completion popup when working in the `text` scope. There are several ways to you can trigger your snippets:

1. **Show on demand**: After typing the "bs3-" prefix for the snippets, you can force the popup to show by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the snippet.
2. **Automatically show**: Add `text.html` to `auto_complete_selector` in your user settings and the popup will always show if there's a match, e.g. after typing the "bs3-html" prefix. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the snippet.
3. **Use the command palette**: It requires some extra-keystrokes, but you can also trigger all snippets from the [command palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html). Open the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and type "bs3-html" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I tried it with ctrl+Space but it does not work in the html file but I see some sugestions in the js file but it does not look the same as in his Video as an Input field!

Comment: The look is defined by the theme you're using

Comment: but do u have any idea why am I getting nothing in the html file when pressing cltr+ space  as the guy in the YouTube Video?

Comment: Did you tweak the `auto_complete_selector` as suggested? What's your exact setting?

Comment: Yes, I have added the following ""auto_complete_selector": "source"" to my Settings user but without seccuss. the entry is the last one in the Settings user file, therefor it is without comma.

Comment: As I have said in my answer, you have to add `text` (or `text.html` or `text.html.plain`) to the setting, e.g. `"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"`. I've refined my answer if that wasn't clear before!

Comment: I tried it too but nothing pops up when pressing ctrl+space. I am starting with plain html file also nothing appears  I want to get the bootstrap template as the guy :( .

Comment: The guy in the video uses the command palette. I find that unnecessarily complicated since it requires extra keystrokes, but nevertheless I've added that to my answer.